Pseudo-regression as a way of checking MANOVA-assumptions
I stumbled across an online tutorial (a YT-series for supposedly a graduate course in statistics) for implementing a MANOVA-test in R. Before carrying out the test, important assumptions are being tested. The author deploys a fake regression as a means to testing if the the linear combinations of the response variables(dependent variables/ DV) satisfy the assumptions of normality, linearity and homogeneity/homoscedasticity.
Assumptions pertaining to the post:
$\mathbf{Assumption\ 1}$: Dependent variables (i.e. error vectors) are sampled from a multivariate normal distribution.
$\mathbf{Assumption\ 2}$: it is assumed/expected that there's some correlation between these two or more continuous dependent variables (DV). Ideally the relationship between them is linear otherwise MANOVA wouldn't be able to capture and utilize it (little doubts here as some literature don't have this as part this assumptions).
$\mathbf{Assumption\ 3}$: All the dependent variables (DV) display homogeneity of the covariance and variance.
Here's the specific set-up in R-code and how the author proceeds:
Suppose we have a design matrix $\mathbf{X}$ containing three columns corresponding to $DV_1$, $DV_2$, $DV_3$.
The author simulates a sample with the same number of random observations based on chi2 distribution in R.
random <- rchisq( nrow($\mathbf{X}$), df)  

This 'random' then serves as the response variable of the following fake regression with $DV_1$, $DV_2$, $DV_3$:
fake <- lm(random ~ . , data=$\mathbf{X}$)  

By using rstudent(), the standardized the residuals (as the author calls it) are retrieved for a residual analysis/ diagnostic analysis.
standardized <- rstudent(fake)  

The rational being because the simulated response variable 'random' is chi2-distributed and has minimal correlation with the $DVs$, the regression line is simply a straight line and the residuals are also random variables with a chi2-distribution. The standardized residuals (rstudent(fake)) are on the other hand normally distributed, which enables us to check if assumptions of normality and linearity are reasonably fulfilled by inspecting histogram and QQ-plot.
R-code
Normality:
hist(standardized)  

Linearity:
qqnorm(standardized) 

Then the author standardizes the fitted values of the fake regression according to the code below for ease of visual comparison and check the assumption of shared constant variance and covariance.
R-code
Homogeneity/homoscedasticity:
fitted <- scale(fake$fitted.values)  
plot(fitted, standardized )    

So this is the usual fitted vs residuals plot we see in usual OLS-regressions.
Questions:

why a chi2-distribution? Why not a normal distribution so that residuals are normally distributed? And if the QQ-plot and histogram do display a reasonably normal distribution, what do they really indicate as to the DVs?

why the use of rstudent()? The rstudent() function is equivalent to a jackknife test for detecting outliers. I don't see how it can be used in residual diagnostics in this way.

Is it even an appropriate technique for testing these assumptions it purported to test or am I misinterpreting the author? I grapple a little with the underlying logic of this way of checking aforementioned assumptions.
We usually just look at plots of pairwise joint distributions of $DVs$ for ellipse and covariance-variance matrices and see they're reasonably similar.



Would it be possible to link the video series?

@Dave  Here you go! About twenty minutes in. R - Two-Way Between Subjects MANOVA Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O_X9zLYQL4&t=1797s

Please add new information as an edit to the pst, not only as comments! Comments on this site are ephemeral, often only seen by a few, can be deleted
